# How do I solve the deploy serverless error : The provided access key is not authorized for this operation?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless

I want to deploy a Spring Boot Rest API
The serverless.yml look like this:

```
org: steinko
app: helloworld
service: backend

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: java8
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
            - "*"
          Resource: "arn:aws:*"
package:
  artifact: build/libs/backend.jar

functions:
  helloworld:
    handler: org.steinko.helloworld.EntryPoint
    events:
      - http:
          path: /helloworld
          method: get
```

When I run : serverless  deploy

I get the error:

steinko@Steins-MacBook-Pro backend % serverless  deploy

Using local credentials. Add provider credentials via dashboard: https://app.serverless.com/steinko/apps/helloworld/backend/dev/us-east-1/providers

```
    Deploying backend to stage dev (us-east-1)
    
    ✖ Stack backend-dev failed to deploy (0s)
    Environment: darwin, node 14.17.3, framework 3.7.5, plugin 6.1.5, SDK 4.3.2
    Credentials: Local, environment variables
    Docs:        docs.serverless.com
    Support:     forum.serverless.com
    Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
    
    Error:
    Error: The provided access key is not authorized for this operation. - Please contact support and provide this identifier to reference this issue - ZXL92JHX1RX6
        at Object.request (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/@serverless/platform-client/src/utils.js:64:19)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
        at async module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/@serverless/dashboard-plugin/lib/app-uids.js:7:15)
        at async ServerlessEnterprisePlugin.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/@serverless/dashboard-plugin/lib/plugin.js:252:13)
        at async PluginManager.runHooks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/plugin-manager.js:530:9)
        at async PluginManager.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/plugin-manager.js:563:9)
        at async PluginManager.spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/plugin-manager.js:585:5)
        at async before:deploy:deploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/deploy.js:40:11)
        at async PluginManager.runHooks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/plugin-manager.js:530:9)
        at async PluginManager.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/plugin-manager.js:563:9)
        at async PluginManager.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/plugin-manager.js:604:7)
        at async Serverless.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/serverless.js:174:5)
        at async /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/scripts/serverless.js:687:9
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

Remove app and org information from your serverless.yml

Answer (score 0):

Encountered same problem after switching serverless accounts.

For me deleting ~/.serverless ~/.serverlessrc and running `serverless login` again solved the issue.